Probability density for function to have a certain y-value
An at first sight simple problem, to which I couldn't readily find the answer nonetheless.
Assume a real-valued function $y=f(x)$ of a single real variable $x$, on the domain $D=[a,b]$. We can consider it smooth, but not necessarily monotonic (for example, a sine wave).
The question: given that $x$ is uniformly distributed within its domain, what is the probability distribution function of $y$ in the codomain?
Or in layman's terms: How much time does the function spend at each y-value?
Could of course sample this numerically, but curious if a general analytic expression to this problem exists?
The problem sounds like the kind of problems that calculus could address... Maybe it's some kind of integral transformation? I imagine that to construct it might involve a bunch of dirac $\delta$'s or heaviside $\theta$'s? Or some other kind of 'projection to subspaces'?
The problem must have several real-life applications of course: predicting how much time you spend at each altitude when taking on a trip with fixed horizontal velocity (whether as a car, plane, or diver).

Since $f$ is smooth, $[a,b]$ can be partitioned into disjoint subintervals $\{I_j\}_{j\in\mathcal{J}}$ where on each $I_j$, $f$ is either strictly monotonic or constant. We will construct conditional probability measures corresponding to each of these subintervals then combine them using the law of total probability to obtain a probability measure corresponding to the pushforward of $X\sim\mathcal{U}([a,b])$ through $f$. That is, compute the law of the random variable $Y\sim f(X)$. We now consider these two cases.

If $f$ is constant on $I_j$ taking on the value $f_j$, then $$P(Y\in A|X\in I_j) = 1~\iff f_j\in A.$$ We then define $P(Y\in A|X\in I_j) = \mu_j(A)$, where $\mu_j =\delta(y-f_j)$.

If $f$ is strictly monotonic on $I_j$, then we notice that this conditional probability is given by the change of variables formula: $$P(Y\in A|X\in I_j) = P(X\in f^{-1}(A)|X\in I_j) = \frac{P(X\in f^{-1}(A)\bigcap X\in I_j)}{P(X\in I_j)} = \frac{P(X\in f^{-1}(A)\bigcap I_j)}{P(X\in I_j)} =  \int_{A}\frac{1}{m(I_j)}\mathbf{1}_{I_j}(f^{-1}_j(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy} f_j^{-1}(y)\right|dy.$$ Here $f_j^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of the bijection $f_j:I_j\to f(I_j)$. We then have a probability measure $\mu_j = \frac{1}{m(I_j)}\mathbf{1}_{I_j}(f^{-1}_j(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy} f_j^{-1}(y)\right|dy$.


Now recall the law of total probability: $P(A) = \sum_k P(A|B_k)P(B_k)$, where $B_k$s are mutually exclusive and $P(\bigcup_k B_k)=1$.  We apply this to our results so far to obtain the final result
$$
P(Y\in A) = \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} P(Y\in A|X\in I_j)P(X\in I_j) = \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} \mu_j(A) \frac{m(I_j)}{b-a},
$$
where $\mu_j$s are given by the forms specified above for intervals where $f$ is either strictly monotonic or constant. Notice that the events $X\in I_j$ are mutually distinct by construction since the intervals $I_j$ themselves are disjoint. Also notice that $P(\bigcup_j X\in I_j)=1$ since $I_j$ formed a partition of $[a,b]$, so we are fine to apply the law of total probability to these events. If you wished to actually write things as a single integral/density, you can, but things become a bit messy:
$$
P(Y\in A) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_A \sum_{j\in \mathcal{J}_\text{mono}} \mathbf{1}_{I_j}(f^{-1}_j(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy} f_j^{-1}(y)\right| + \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}_\text{const}}m(I_j)\delta(y-f_j)~\mathrm{d}y.
$$

Thanks a lot! Would you mind detailing a bit more the step where you go from probabilities to the integral and derivatives? I think I got an idea what's going on, but might be good to see more explicitly.

It is the standard formula for change of variables of a PDF applied to a uniform density. It is then truncated outside of each interval by the indicator function.
